# How do I create a http redirect url for react native expo app?

Tags: react-native, redirect, oauth, expo

I have a third-party OAuth in my react-native expo app.

I need to specify a https redirect url to the third party website to come back to my app. Right now when I am running my app on expo - I am using auth.expo to redirect to the app and it works fine.

Now, when I want to run it as an independent app, how should I set up redirection in it?
I have searched a lot for it and the solutions that I have found said to modify the AndroidManifest file which is not there in app created via expo.

Can you please guide on how should I proceed?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Could you provide a bit more context or a code example, please? Would help a lot for the people who want to help you out.